# Can I quit my current job after receiving a formal letter from new job?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, contracts, start-date

I accept my first job offer 2 days ago and they send me the copy of the letter signed by me and them.  The start date is set for 2 weeks from now.
My question is should I expect to receive anything else from them during this 2 week? I mean should I now resign (I do not have an actual job I am working with my advisor at the university) and prepare everything for my move (the job is another city.)? Or should I expect to do some paperwork or contract before my start day? They haven't say anything about the contract yet.
I'm in the US!

Comment: I assume you have at least a 2 week notice period on your current job, so you should resign now if you start in two weeks.

Comment: The job offer **is** the "contract". It should [**include everything**](https://www.thebalance.com/job-offer-letter-2061695) you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you currently working? It says it's your first job and you accepted an offer to another city in which you signed. Please edit your post since it's confusing.

Anyways, the best way to handle this is to talk to your new job HR/hiring manager and ask them if there are additional paperwork you need and what to expect.

If you are working, and you got the confirmation with your new job, send in your 2 weeks notice. Look for a new place to live(if you need) and good luck.

Comment: And add:  Expect to be hit with several packets of forms on your first day.  Bring your photo ID, social security card, and a good pen.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean should I now resign (I do not have an actual job I am working with my advisor at the university) and prepare everything for my move

In the US it's typical and expected to provide your current employer a **minimum** of two weeks notice that you will be terminating your employment. Depending on your field and level of responsibility - it may be desirable for this notice to be much greater than two weeks.

You need to contact the company with which you've accepted a job offer and determine the requirements if any BEFORE your first day. Chances are since you've been given none to this point that there wont be any and that you should be prepared to hit the ground running on your first day.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is should I expect to receive anything else from them during this 2 week? I mean should I now resign and prepare everything for my move (the job is another city.)?

**Most likely you will have to serve your Notice Period on your current company** so make sure you resign within due time so you are able to fulfill your period and start the new job on your start date.

*Hopefully* your Notice Period is the "standard" two-week notice, so you can be able to do this smoothly. If this is not the case, I suggest you contact your future company to sort this out.

> Or should I expect to do some paperwork or contract before my start day?

This would depend on your future company, they may or may not ask you for something else. However, you must make sure your paperwork and notice are in order before such period. That is what you have to worry about.